# foreach loop doesn't execute the variable

Tags: powershell, if-statement, port

I wrote a few lines of code to check if a port is open or not:

```
$ports = @(5353,5672,8080,4443,15672,9200)

foreach ($port in $ports)
    {   
    TNC -ComputerName localhost -Port $port -InformationLevel Quiet -WarningAction SilentlyContinue | Tee-Object -Variable CheckPortStatus > $null  
        if ($CheckPortStatus -eq "True") 
            {$status = Write-Host "Open" -ForegroundColor GREEN}
        else
            {$status = Write-Host "close" -ForegroundColor RED} 
    echo "the port is $status"
```

I don't get why the output is this:

[image]

The script actually works but it execute the variable when declared and then it doesn't use the variable after the `if/else`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Write-Host` cmdlet just *prints* something to the console, it **doesn't return** anything so you can't assign it to `$status`. Instead you should do something like this:

```
$ports = @(5353,5672,8080,4443,15672,9200)

foreach ($port in $ports)
{   
    TNC -ComputerName localhost -Port $port -InformationLevel Quiet -WarningAction SilentlyContinue | Tee-Object -Variable CheckPortStatus > $null  
    if ($CheckPortStatus -eq "True") 
    {
        $status = "Open"
        Write-Host $status -ForegroundColor GREEN
    }
    else
    {
        $status = "Closed"
        Write-Host $status -ForegroundColor RED
    } 

    Write-Host "the port is $status"
}
```

[Quote from Jeffrey Snover:](http://www.jsnover.com/blog/2013/12/07/write-host-considered-harmful/)

> When you are writing or reviewing PowerShell scripts, I’d like you to
>   remember the following rule of thumb:
>
> **Using Write-Host is almost always wrong.**

Comment: Thank you @Martin Brandl, I will remember not to use `Write-Host`